# Charge distribution on conductors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, conductors

Consider a metal sphere $S_1$ with radius $R_1$ and charge $Q_1$. If another metal sphere $S_2$, of radius $R_2$ and no charge at all, touches the first, how much charge is transferred to the second sphere? I understand we can use the fact that the surface of a conductor is an equipotential surface to answer that question, but is there another way to explain what happens without reference to potential? There are multiple factors whose contributions I'm trying to understand. The distribution of charge on $S_1$ (uniform vs non-uniform), the dimensions of each sphere ($R_1\ and\ R_2$), the geometry of the conductor (spheres vs other shapes) and the type of material. My guesses are that 1) If there are no external agent causing the charge to be non-uniformly distributed, it will distribute itself uniformly over the surface, for otherwise there would be forces between regions of different densities that balance out when the distribution is uniform. From this, we can conclude that 2) the charge will distribute itself uniformly over the second sphere as well such that both spheres have the same density, but I'm not so sure about that. If it's true, then 3) the equality of charge densities directly tells us how the radii affect the amount of charge transferred. But those don't say what happens in the case of different shapes, particularly shapes with edges like cubes or triangles, nor the effect of the type of material.

Comment: I don't see why the charge distribution on the surface of the two balls touching (pause) would be uniform as you assumed. The force balancing will give uniform charge when the force is local, but electrostatic is a long range force. The charge distribution on a single isolated sphere is uniform because of symmetry. The uniformity is not true in general in order to minimizing energy. For instance, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302711/is-the-electric-field-generated-by-surface-charges-on-conductor-always-outgoing